# Recommend a new e-book reader, main need is highlight and add notes to my books

Tags: pdf, kobo, adobe-reader

I have an e-book reader ( in fact it is a gift) Kobo aura. 
The problem I faced with this e-book is that  I am not able to highlight in pdf files, nor add  some notes  to my pdf books as in adobe reader.

I don't know if there is a way to do this with this kobo version, even though I tried to authorize it with my adobe reader account.

My question is that, which e-book reader have such properties? i.e. allow highlighting and adding notes to the books, since I am planning to buy a new one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most (if not all) will not allow highlighting PDFs. The Kobo and many other readers all use RMSDK, which is Adobe's rendering engine for ePubs and PDFs. RMSDK does not support highlighting PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only be using PDF files, then either the **Sony DPT-RP1** or the smaller **Sony DPT-CP1** will allow you to add notes and highlight *directly* on the PDF file itself. You can then transfer the modified file to your computer and share it however you want. Those readers will even allow you to take any type of handwritten notes. However, the only way these features work is with the use of the electronic pen that is included with the device. There is also the **reMarkable** which even allows you to transform your handwritten notes into typed text.